# login function from external class is not working

Tags: php, class, oop, authentication

What is wrong with my login function?

This is defined in the class 'Auth':

```
public function login($username,$password)
{
  $loggedin = false;
  $password = $this->hashData($password);
  $query = "SELECT `Username`, `PWhash` FROM 'user' WHERE 'Username' = '$username'LIMIT 1";

  if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)){

    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
      $dbuser = $obj->Username;
      $dbpwd = $obj->PWhash;

      if ($dbpwd == $password){
        $loggedin = true;
      }
      else{
        $loggedin = false;
        exit;
      }
      mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
  }
```

This is the function hashData() that I used (also defined in the same class):

```
protected function hashData($data){
  return hash_hmac('sha512', $data);
}
```

This is how I tried to use the function (class included in this site with require_once('auth.php'))

```
$var = new Auth; // instantiating ... seems to work fine
$var->login($username, $password); // this does not work
```

Comment: Wrap off quotes `WHERE 'Username'` from here use backtick

Comment: @Saty and `'user'` aswell.

Comment: and add space before limit  `'$username' LIMIT`

Comment: Thanks. I replaced the 's with `s and added the forgotten space, but it is still not working. Not sure if I understand what you mean by "wrap off qotes", tried translating it but I don't really understand.

Comment: you haven't said what the problem is. "it doesn't work" is not a problem.